# Try to parse a gridview cell value to any type (validation)

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, datagridview

I'm trying to validate what the user inputs in an editable gridview.
I use the event CellLeave to validate the input, like this:

```
private void membersGrid_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Datatable that will hold the schema for the Members table
    DataTable dtMeta;

    // SqlDataAdapter is already filled and is now used to get the metadata
    daAllMembers.FillSchema(dtMeta, SchemaType.Source);

    // Define a type instance of the current column from the metadata table dtMeta
    System.Type cellType = dtMeta.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataType;

    // Get an object from the editted cell
    Object objCellValue = membersGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

    // This is where i'm stuck, how can I do this?
    cellType.TryParse(objCellValue);
}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. I basically want to tryparse the object into the type defined in the metadata for that table.

Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to validate text input.  Other cell types, like a check box or combo box, naturally restrict user input.  You could do the following:

1. Make an abstract class that derives from DataGridViewTextBoxCell:

   public abstract class MyTextBox : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
   {
       virtual bool ValidateTextInput();
   }
2. Derive a class from this base class for each of the different types of data grid view cell types that you want to validate.  For example:

   public class StateCell : MyTextBox
   {
       override ValidateTextInput()
       {
           // verify that the text is a valid state abbreviation
       }
   }
3. Place your custom, validating data grid view cell types into your data grid view (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx).